# How to put inline Ruby each loop in an external request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I'm using Rails 3.1 and the paypal_adaptive ( https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive ) gem in order to make an API request to Paypal. Here's the deal: I have a request which I'm making to Paypal in a controller. I have a collection of Items (which is @items here), and I'm trying to add recipients to that request for each item in that collection. Here's my code:

```
pay_request = PaypalAdaptive::Request.new

data = {
  "returnUrl" => "http://testserver.com/payments/completed_payment_request",
  "requestEnvelope" => {"errorLanguage" => "en_US"},
  "currencyCode" => "USD",
  "receiverList" => {"receiver"=>[
    @items.each do |item|
      {"email"=>"#{Recipient.find_by_id(item.recip_id).email}", "amount"=>"#{item.price}"},
    end
  ]},
  "cancelUrl"=>"http://testserver.com/payments/canceled_payment_request",
  "actionType"=>"PAY",
  "ipnNotificationUrl"=>"http://testserver.com/payments/ipn_notification"
}

pay_response = pay_request.pay(data)

if pay_response.success?
  redirect_to pay_response.approve_paypal_payment_url
else
  puts pay_response.errors.first['message']
  redirect_to failed_payment_url
end
```

...but this isn't working. How can I properly insert Ruby syntax into this request?

(Sorry for the vagueness in the title. I'm unsure what kind of request I'm making (AJAX maybe?))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just collect all the items into a variable and set that as the value of the "reciever" key:

```
recipients = @items.each do |item|
  {"email"=>"#{Recipient.find_by_id(item.recip_id).email}", "amount"=>"#{item.price}"}
end

...

"currencyCode"=>"USD",  
"receiverList"=>{"receiver"=> recipients},
"cancelUrl"=>"http://testserver.com/payments/canceled_payment_request",
```

Comment: Good idea. I'm getting an error though: it's giving me a bunch of syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end exceptions. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Fixed my example. There was a trailing comma on the second line. That being said, this is a pretty basic question. You could save your self a lot of time waiting for answers to questions like this by checking out a good ruby book or resource (ie: the Pickaxe book, which is free: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)